# InlineEditSupport With Validation

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I am trying to use apex:inlineEditSupport to help the end-user to a better experience, but it has a major problem, **saving a record modified with this tag does not enforce validation rules!**

I looked at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3946/how-to-override-salesforce-standard-object-controller-save-method-to-intercept-i) and started playing around with the sfdcPage object, but I haven't found anything yet. Should I abandon this component and just use an edit page? Is this a known bug (or even a bug)? Has anyone found a workaround?

Sample code:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pageContent" mode="inlineEdit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="pageContent" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" rerender="pageContent" immediate="true" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.FieldSets.InlineEditSupport_Fields}" var="field">
                <apex:outputField value="{!MyObject__c[field]}" />
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Are you using the standard controller or a controller extension?  And, if the latter, where is the {!save} action bound to?